# How to remove the x-axis in a point plot ggplot (see picture)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a formatting question about ggplot point graphs. The y-axis goes from 0-10, on the x-axis there are two groups: experimental and control. The groups have datapoints for all 10 y values. The problem is, that for the y=0 values, the points are not depicted as full spheres but half spheres. 
So, to illustrate, the spheres on y=0 row are now as with "control", and I want them to be as with "experimental", as shown here:

[image]

How can I change this? I already tried to remove the x-axis using

```
 theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
   axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
   panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
   panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

But that didn't do the trick...

Comment: try `...+coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank's so much :)